# Microsoft Access - assistance with a query

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, sql-update, ms-access-2010

I have the following table structure:

```
tbl_workShift
id          PK
employeeid  FK
logInTime   <- full date
logOutTime  <- full date
```

I am trying to create a time sheet for employees to use. It will be fairly simple to use; an employee will select themself from a dropdownmenu and click login || logout.

the login button just inserts a new record.

This happens only when the employee wants to logout

```
If(Datediff("h",logInTime,Now())>9)
 ->create a  new record
  ->insert logOutTime = NOW() ( since the employee forgot to log out yesterday/login today)
else
 ->update last record with logOutTime = now() ( he didn't forget to login that same day)
```

I am having trouble with the logout button - I can't seem to figure out how to write this SQL query.

Comment: What is your code **not** doing, that you want it to do?

Comment: I can't seem to get my logout working correctly, mostly selecting the correct record and updating it with the correct information... mostly look at my If statement, this is what I want to replicate.

Comment: What is / are the SQL statement/s you have tried?

Comment: @Fionnuala I know how to write the `SELECT` statement to get the last record created by the employee. `Inserting / Updating` doesn't seem to be a issue; its more about writing the if statement in SQL `(dateDiff("h",logInTime,Now())>9)`.

Comment: Currently having trouble with getting a single value from a specific record to a variable, so I can later use it in my IF statement. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if I have enough information about what you are doing to give you the help you are looking for...

But this vba code might help you figure it out.

```
Private Sub Employee_AfterUpdate()


Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb


Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * From tbl_workshift Where employeeid = " & Me!EmployeeId & ";")

If rs.EOF Then
    MsgBox "Employee not found."
    Exit Sub
Else
    If DateDiff("h", Me!LogInTime, Now()) > 9 Then
        rs.AddNew
            rs!logOutTime = Now()
        rs.Update
    Else
        rs.MoveLast
            rs.Edit
            rs!logOutTime = Now()
        rs.Update
    End If

    rs.Close

End If


End Sub
```

Good luck.